# How do I hide the tags <a>link when tags has alt="*-slide" as i have an unkown number of tags?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="slide">
<a href="#"><h1 alt="">test</h1></a>
<a href="#"><h1 alt="1-slide">test1</h1></a>
<a href="#"><h1 alt="2-slide">test2</h1></a>
<a href="#">   <h1 alt="3-slide">test3</h1>    </a>
</div>
```

Based on the above code snippet,

How do I hide the tags link when tags has alt="*-slide" as i have an unkown number of tags?

Comment: Throw away that code and write valid HTML instead.

Comment: hide alt="1-slide" to alt="3-slide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, use selector.

The `[alt$="-slide"]` select only alt finishing with "-slide".

The `[alt^="-slide"]` select only alt starting with "-slide".

```css
h1[alt$="-slide"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
        <h1 alt="">test</h1>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <h1 alt="1-slide">test1</h1>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <h1 alt="2-slide">test2</h1>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <h1 alt="3-slide">test3</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer solve your problem you can check it on the left side